# How to conditionally format Kendo UI grid cell (depending on values) razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui, conditional-statements

Is there a way to conditionally format `Kendo UI` grid cell depending on value in that cell. I would also want to add a class to grid cell depending on value. 
(`ASP.net`, `C#`, `Razor`)

P.S

Solution

Ah i've figured it out.

```
<script>
    function onDataBound(e) {
        $('td').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == 'Condition') {
                $(this).addClass('customClass');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Grid looks like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomStylesOnDataBound.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel>()
              .Name("mvcGrid")


              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeId).Width(100);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Width(75);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(75);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Address);
              })
              .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
              .Filterable()
              .Pageable()
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()                                
                .PageSize(50)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Employees_Read", "Home"))
            )
)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better solution to this but it gets the job done. Ty Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is covered in [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/ajax-binding-custom-row-styles-based-on-the-data.aspx) code library article.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but this is only useful for formating entire row, while i only need to format single cell depending on value. Is it possible to modify it for single cell only?

Comment: I've added solution to the original post!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `$(e.sender.element).find('td').each` for the selector.

Adding `$(e.sender.element)` will limit your search to just the grid, otherwise if you have multiple tables on your from, you find the cells in the other tables too.

Also if you use `$(e.sender.element).find('tr').each`, then you can use `$(this.cells[0]).text()` to check various columns in your grid and your class assignment would look like this: `$(this.cells[1]).addClass('customClass');`